# Python judge whether each line contains the specific words

Tags: python

I want to judge whether each line contains some specific words, like price,key,area and so on.If a line contains one of the words, the column starnum would be 1. If a line contains two of the words, the column
starnum would be 2. I tried the code below, but it was really slow to get the result. The data has over 90 thousand rows.
So how could I improve my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

io=r'D:/test.xlsx'
data1=pd.read_excel(io,sheet_name=0)


data1['starnum']=0
l=len(data1)
print (l)

if data1['content'] is np.nan:
    data1['content']=''

data1['content']=data1['content'].str

for i in range(l):
    if data1.loc[i,'content'].find('price')>0:
        data1.loc[i,'starnum']+=1
for i in range(l):
    if data1.loc[i,'content'].find('area')>0:
        data1.loc[i,'starnum']+=1

for i in range(l):
    if data1.loc[i,'content'].find('key')>0:
        data1.loc[i,'starnum']+=1

print (data1)
```

Comment: Instead of looping manually with `loc`, did you try `data1['content'].apply`?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.      def function(s):
    if s.find('price')>0:
        return 1

data1['starnum']=data1['content'].apply(function)

Comment: What do you expect `find` to return? I haven't seen a similar function

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to take in the string of `'content'` column and count the sub-strings in it and then sum the counts

```
df['starnum'] = df.content.apply(lambda s: sum(s.count(t) for t in ['price', 'area', 'key']))
```